# Export user controls in vb 2010 to a text file

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

Is it possible to export the user controls properties from my VB project to a text file or to excel. I have tried google ,but today google isn't my friend. I am using VB 2010 express

thanks

Comment: I have created a program in written in vb using vb 2010 express. I want a list of all the controls (buttons labels etc) and their properties.

Comment: It already works that way.  Click the Show All Files icon in Solution Explorer, open the node next to the form and double-click the Designer.vb file.  That's text.  And code.  If you want it in another format then you'll have to write your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Const path = "C:\Test.txt"
Dim query = From assembly In My.Application.Info.LoadedAssemblies
            From type In assembly.GetTypes
            Where type.IsSubclassOf(GetType(UserControl))
            From prop In type.GetProperties
            Select PropInfo = String.Format("{0}{3}{1}{3}{2}",
                              assembly.GetName().Name,
                              type.Name, 
                              prop.Name,
                              vbTab)

If query.Any Then
      IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, query)
End If
```

Modify the LINQ query to your exact requirement. For example if you only want public properties with set-accessor that is writable:

```
 Where prop.CanWrite AndAlso Not prop.GetSetMethod Is Nothing AndAlso prop.GetSetMethod.IsPublic
```